# Python: Sólo permitir números en un campo de formulario entry tkinter

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

Estoy tratando de que en un campo de formulario con tkinter sólo se puedan ingresar números. Los campos serían ci y teléfono.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
from tkinter import messagebox

ventana=Tk()
ventana.geometry("900x600+0+0")
ventana.title("SGDF")

def ventana_cliente():


    def ventana_agregar():
    #windows.withdraw()
        window=tk.Toplevel()
        window.geometry("512x512")
        e1=tk.Label(window, text="AGREGAR CLIENTE :",bg="white",fg="black").place(x=50, y=50),



 # variable nombre
        entrynombre=tk.StringVar()
        nombretx=tk.Entry(window,textvariable=entrynombre).place(x=50, y=150)


# variable  ci
        entryci=tk.StringVar()
        citx=tk.Entry(window,textvariable=  entryci).place(x=50, y=235)

# variable  telefono

        entrytelefono=tk.StringVar()
        telefonotx=tk.Entry(window,textvariable=  entrytelefono).place(x=50, y=320)


# Etiqueta para "INGRESE NOMBRE O EMPRESA" x=30, y=115
        etiquetanombre=tk.Label(window, text="NOMBRE O EMPRESA.", padx=10 ).place(x=30, y=115)



#Etiqueta para "INGRESE CI O RUT"
        etiquetaci = tk.Label(window, text="INGRESE CI O RUT", padx=10 ).place(x=30, y=200)


#Etiqueta para "TELEFONO"
        etiquetatelefono = tk.Label(window, text="TELEFONO", padx=10 ).place(x=30, y=285)

## Boton menu  

        menu=tk.Button(window, text="MENU", fg="red",font=("arial", 12),cursor = "hand2",relief = "raised",command = window.destroy)
        menu.pack()
        menu.place(x=50,y=370)

        def guarda():

                db = sqlite3.connect("sgdf.s3db")
                c = db.cursor()

                nombre = entrynombre.get()
                ci = entryci.get()
                telefono = entrytelefono.get()


                c.execute("insert into cliente (nombre,ci,telefono) values ('"+nombre+"','"+ci+"','"+telefono+"')")
                db.commit()
                c.close()
                messagebox.showinfo("MODIFICACION","CLIENTE INGRESADO" )
                window.destroy()
                ventana_agregar()

        btguardar = tk.Button(window, text =  "GUARDAR", fg="blue",font=("arial", 12),cursor = "hand2",relief = "raised",command = guarda)
        btguardar.pack()
        btguardar.place(x=300,y=370)
```

Comment: Bienvenida @Valeria Espinosa a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar la función `isdigit()` para comprobar que el texto introducido es numérico.

Tal vez te sirva este código:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


# Tkinter Python 3.7
from tkinter import *

def ventana():
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Tkinter")
    window.geometry('350x200')
    lbl = Label(window, text="Introduce un número")
    lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
    result = Label(window,text="")
    txt = Entry(window,width=10)
    txt.grid(column=1, row=0)
    result.grid(column=3,row=0)
    txt.focus()
    def mensaje():
        res = txt.get()
        #aquí compruebas que es un número
        res = int(res) if res.isdigit() else 0
        result.configure(text= res)
        txt.delete(0, END)

    btn = Button(window, text="Activa", bg="red",fg="white", command=mensaje)
    btn.grid(column=2, row=0)
    window.mainloop()


def main():
    ventana()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo intentaría, dejando todo como lo tienes si te funciona bien, modificar la función `guarda()` de la siguiente forma:

```
def guarda():

            db = sqlite3.connect("sgdf.s3db")
            c = db.cursor()

            nombre = entrynombre.get()
            ci = entryci.get()
            telefono = entrytelefono.get()

            if ci.isdigit() and telefono.isdigit():
                c.execute("insert into cliente (nombre,ci,telefono) values ('"+nombre+"','"+ci+"','"+telefono+"')")
                db.commit()
                c.close()
                messagebox.showinfo("MODIFICACION","CLIENTE INGRESADO" )
                window.destroy()
                ventana_agregar()
            else:
                # Aquí puedes añadir un mensaje con `messagebox` o simplemente un `print` que te diga por consola que debes introducir solamente números en los campos requeridos.
                print('Error: Debes introducir únicamente números en los campos ci y telefono')
```

De esta forma si `ci` y `telefono` son dígitos, el programa continuará normal y si no saltará al mensaje de error.

Nota: `if ci.isdigit()` es equivalente a poner `if ci.isdigit() == True`